# Speeding up a SQLite database android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a database of objects. Each of these objects contains two `strings` and two `bitmaps`. When I do a `getAllContacts()` call to my database, the loading takes quite a while. For me its not a problem, but for the end-users, this would be annoying. When I load an object I set this options to my bitmaps saying:

```
  BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inSampleSize = 8;
```

Which will shrink the `Bitmaps` to 1/8 of the original height and width. But still, it takes around 10-15 seconds to load 50 records and fill this into a `ListView`. Is there any way I can check if the object I try to load is in the memory, also called `paging`? Or maybe I can load the Bitmaps, when the users presses one of the items in the `ListView`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution:**

So, finally I found a solution to my problem. Instead of getting all of the `Bitmaps` when I do a `getAllContact()` call, the bitmap's is loaded when the user presses a row in the `ListView` This is whats done in the `setOnClickListener` method in CustomAdapter for my `ListView`

```
String PCN = cases.get(position).getCaseNumber(); 
int tempPCN = Integer.valueOf(PCN); 
tempBitMapArray = dbHandler.getFinger(tempPCN); 

Bitmap left = tempBitMapArray[0]; 
Bitmap right = tempBitMapArray[1]; 

ByteArrayOutputStream bs1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
left.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bs1);

ByteArrayOutputStream bs2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
right.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bs2);
```

And the `getFinger(...)` method:

```
    public Bitmap[] getFinger(int pcn) {

    Bitmap[] fingers = new Bitmap[2]; 

    String SQLQUERY = "SELECT " + RIGHTFINGER + ", " + LEFTFINGER +" FROM " + TABLE_CASES  + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + "=" + pcn + ";"; 

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQLQUERY, null); 
    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                byte[] blob1 = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("leftFinger"));
                Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob1, 0, blob1.length, options);

                byte[] blob2 = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("rightFinger")); 
                Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob2, 0, blob2.length, options);

                fingers[0] = bmp1; 
                fingers[1] = bmp2;
                return fingers;

               } while(cursor.moveToNext());
      }
      return null; 
}
```

I hope this example will give other people a pinpoint in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You set the sample size but it's still reading (I assume) large images. Why not set your bitmaps so that they are already small and then you can read small images without the scale factor applied?

I had a listView in my own code doing similar things and it was very slow until I wrote code to shrink each new image as it was created and then always just dealt with small images. And the code lived happily ever after.

Comment: This is because I need the full size of the Bitmaps on a Server-Side, for some algorithms stuff.

Comment: What about creating a full-sized version and a small version of the bitmap?

Comment: @ikh Thanks for your input, I will consider this. But as for now I will try to load the image, when the user presses on item in the listview.